# Sharepoint 2010 User Code Host service is not starting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

When I look in the services.msc console and look at the SharePoint 2010 User Code Host and click on Start, it gets started, but stops in less than 10 seconds. I'm not sure whats happening, but because of this, user contacts are not updated on SharePoint.

How can I fix this so user profiles and contacts are updated?

Answer (score 1):

In order to start the User code Host services, you have to follow steps.

- add the account( under which Service will Run) into the local admin. Only during the starting process, once started take this out from local admin.
- Now,browse `Central Admin->Application Management->Manage Services on Server` and from here start the service.
- Once it started then you can confirm from the MMC, this service should be started over their.

Dont try to start it from MMC, always start it from Central admin.

read more here: http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/06/starting-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-code.html

Comment: When I look into the Manage Services on Server I could see that the User Profile service and User Profile Synchronization service is already started but I stopped it and restarted it again but still no imporvement. The problem I am facing in when I go into services.msc and  look for "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host" that service is not starting even if I click on start it stops automatically in less than 5 seconds. The Startup type is set to automatically but this is not starting. I guess this is the issue. Is there any suggestion on what I can do to make this working.

Comment: i am not telling you to start/stop the User profile....I am telling start "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service " service from sharepoint central admin.

Comment: Yes, that is also started but still the same issue.

Comment: did you see any error in the event log, why it is stoping? also under which account it is being started. Try to stop it and restart the server then start the service from central admin.

Comment: I never checked event log. But I did stop and start in central adminstration but still this issue exist.

Comment: check the event log, it will give the clue why it is stopping? some permission issue or somthing else?

Comment: also check this kb article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2021539

Comment: I feel like the issue is with the Sync job. Do you have any idea how to check the sync job in central administration

Comment: how do you feel it is sync job issue? you can run the user profile sync crawl this will tell u if it is running or not?

Comment: I checked the Application Event log and I could see lot of FIMSynchronizationService errors an also there is a lot of DistributedCOM error. Not sure if they a related and one of my collegues was saying it feels like sync job is not doing it job and thats why this issue is there

Comment: My error                                                                                         Service Control manager error
The SharePoint 2010 User Code Host service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 615 time(s).

Comment: Sharepoint server error
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance 
(f252729d-3e02-4ee7-b007-b59aabc8e78e).

Comment: DistributedCOM error
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{000C101C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be 
modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: those are my error

Comment: looks like you have problem with all services....did you try the fix mentioned in the above KB article...chaning the registry key

Comment: Do you mean changing the registry subkey for the value 0

Comment: yes as per the kb...HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance\Disable Performance Counters

Comment: i went into the registry sub key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance under performance at default change the data to 0

Comment: i didnot see Disable performance counters

Comment: I will be happy to discuss this through email also if you can. Your help and suggestion are making me understand more depth on the issue.

Comment: which area u are?i am happy to assist you as time permit.

Comment: i am in the boston area. I am available anytime during and no working hours also

Comment: evening is the best time, when i will be out from office

Comment: thank you, we can discuss this in the evening. you can email me at: shoeb.kool@gmail.com so we can create chat to discuss

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32625/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-sharepoint-2010-user-code-host-is-not).

Comment: I see the major error is the event id 6482 application service job failed for service instance. I am really confused on what it wants me to do? Any suggestion

Comment: you can try to run the config wizard on the servers( all)...just run without changing option.